# How to edit image metadata?

Tags: java, image, metadata

I want to read PNG or JPEG images metadata then modify them and finally save them.

I found a really good library ([metadata-extractor](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor)), so I can now read the image metadata by doing:

```java
Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(new File("test.png"));
for (Directory d : metadata.getDirectories()) {
    for (Tag t : d.getTags()) {
        System.out.println(t);
    }
}
```

Then I can create a directory and add a tag into it:

```java
Directory d = new CustomDirectory();
metadata.addDirectory(d);
d.setInt(0, 123);
```

Here is the CustomDirectory class:

```java
import java.util.HashMap;

import com.drew.metadata.Directory;
import com.drew.metadata.TagDescriptor;

public class CustomDirectory extends Directory {

    public CustomDirectory() {
        super();
        setDescriptor(new TagDescriptor<CustomDirectory>(this));
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Custom";
    }

    @Override
    protected HashMap<Integer, String> getTagNameMap() {
        HashMap<Integer, String> tagNameMap = new HashMap<>();
        tagNameMap.put(0, "A test tag");
        return tagNameMap;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the changes are not saved. <s>Is it possible to save the changes using this library? If not, how can I achieve this?</s> In fact, it isn't possible to use this library to write metadata. Is there another library that can do that?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/metadata/package-summary.html